# Choose the number of mtry (without cause bias)?

Tags: r, tree

I have this (example) code and I am trying to understand some characteristics. There are many questions about `Random Forest` and always comes up the issue of the `number of trees` and the `mtry`. This data frame is just an example but how can I explain the plot of the model (error) in order to set the number of trees without cause bias? Also the `No. of variables tried at each split` equals to 1 here (why?)
I think `tuneR` and `train` may cause bias so I want to try to find the best number of `trees` and `mtry` (default p/3) based on the error.

```
#' an example of a data frame and the model 
clin=data.frame(1:500)
clin$k=clin$X1.500*0.2
clin$z=clin$X1.500*14.1/6
names(clin)=c("pr1","pr2","res")

rf=randomForest(res~pr1+pr2,data=clin,ntree=1000,importance=TRUE,keep.inbag=T)
plot(rf)
rf
    Call:
 randomForest(formula = res ~ pr1 + pr2, data = clin, ntree = 1000,      importance = TRUE, keep.inbag = T) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 1000
No. of variables tried at each split: 1

          Mean of squared residuals: 2.051658
                    % Var explained: 100
```

Answer (score 1):

The RF is based on a subset of the total number of predictors *p* (*p*/3). In this example you only have 2 predictors to explain "res". RF will therefore only randomly select one.

*ntree* and *mtry* should be defined so that your results are consistent.
If you set *ntree* too low and compute the RF multiple times you'll see a huge variation in RMSEP between the different RF.
The same holds true for *mtry*.

[A previous answer with reference to Breiman's paper on the matter](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7295/what-should-be-the-optimal-parameters-for-random-forest-classifier)

edit regarding the predictor chosen for the split: when dealing with large numbers of predictors (2 is definitely too low to make good use of a RF) you may be interested in variable importance to see which one are more meaningful than the others.

Comment: Thank you for your reply (and the link). You said that RF randomly select one, how can I see which one?

Comment: getTree() will extract a tree and then you can see which predictor is used. See the full documentation fom the randomForest package for additional information.